# CSS3: keeping :after and :before elements aligned with the element's height

Tags: css, pseudo-element

Im having a big headcache with a header design:

[image]

Here the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uGECm/

The idea is to have the gray label that 'wrap' the element; However, the label's height is unknow (it can vary by its content) - my problem is that the 2 pseudo-elements made like triangles get a wrong position if the labels change the size, this becose they're position is relative.

Any idea?

**ps: im looking for a no-js and no-images solution.**

Comment: Nice use of CSS border triangles.

Comment: @MattCoughlin thanks, i saw them here: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
section h2:before, section h2:after {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0 0 -10px 0;
}

section h2:before {
    content: '\0000a0';
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid #323232;
}

section h2:after {
    content: '\0000a0';
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid #323232;
    right: 0;
}​
```

Here's a fork with some further CSS formatting: http://jsfiddle.net/bqXeJ/

It's worth taking a look at a style guide [like the one I wrote here](http://jezenthomas.co.uk/a-better-css-style-guide/), and also, if you use Lea Verou's [prefixfree.js](http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/), you can skip writing declarations for each browser vendor.

Comment: Glad it helped. I added some extra information that I think is worth looking at too.

Answer (score 1):

You can position the pseudoelements absolutely. Since `section h2` is `position: relative`, setting them to `top: 100%` will keep them stuck at the bottom, regardless of the parent's size:

```
section h2:before, section h2:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- Use absolute rather than relative position for :before and :after
- Apply `bottom:-10px;` to both
- Apply `left:0;` and `right:0;`, respectively.
- Remove the float. Floating has no effect on an element with absolute position.

Updated [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/uGECm/5/).

```
section h2:before,
section h2:after {
    content: '\0000a0';
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;    
    bottom: -10px;
    display: block;
}
section h2:before {
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid #323232;
    left: 0;
}
section h2:after {
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid #323232;
    right: 0;
}
```